# vbscript to powershell script

Tags: powershell, vbscript

Wondering if someone would be kind enough to help

Is it possible to create a script which list all files in a folder which begin with a particular name, thereafter output the file names to a text file and then create registry key values based on the outputted file names ?

In terms of a vbscript, I have the following thus far ( in sections), but cannot:

- Figure out how to output file names which begin with a particular name or contain xyz
- How to pass the file names as registry values ( in the WshShell.RegWrite  section below)
- How to join the two sections in one script

> ```
> Dim fso
> Dim ObjFolder
> Dim ObjOutFile
> Dim ObjFiles
> Dim ObjFile
> ```

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set ObjFolder = fso.GetFolder("C:\JetInfo")

Set ObjOutFile = fso.CreateTextFile("C:\WindowsFiles.txt")

Set ObjFiles = ObjFolder.Files

For Each ObjFile In ObjFiles
    ObjOutFile.WriteLine(ObjFile.Name & String(50 - Len(ObjFile.Name), " "))
Next

ObjOutFile.Close

Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

WshShell.RegWrite "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\NewSignature", "INPUT FILE NAME HERE", "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. (What in particular are you having trouble with?)

Answer (score 1):

- Output file names that begin with a particular string:

  ```
  str = "foobar"

  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\JetInfo").Files
    If LCase(Left(f.Name, Len(str))) = LCase(str) Then
      WScript.Echo f.Name
    End If
  Next
  ```

  Output file names that contain a particular string:

  ```
  str = "foobar"

  For Each f In fso.GetFolder("C:\JetInfo").Files
    If InStr(LCase(f.Name), str) > 0 Then
      WScript.Echo f.Name
    End If
  Next
  ```
- Write a file name to the registry:

  ```
  Set f = fso.GetFile("C:\path\to\some.file")

  WshShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\14.0\Common\NewSignature" _
    , Chr(34) & Replace(f.Path, "\", "\\") & Chr(34), "REG_EXPAND_SZ"
  ```

As for your third question: what values do you want to create from the files? It would be quite pointless to overwrite the same value again and again.

Comment: Many thanks for your help. In terms of output file names that contain a particular string, is it possible to output file names that contain a particular string and also have a particular file extension ? I need to create registry values based on the file names, as these values set certain settings in a program.

Comment: Sure it's possible. The relevant method for this is [`GetExtensionName()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x0fxha2a%28v=vs.84%29.aspx). However, you still didn't explain which values you actually want to create. As I said, it doesn't make any sense to overwrite the same value multiple times.